# How do I break an imported .obj file into its individual parts?

Tags: export, import

I have exported an .obj file from AC3d (see image)
Each colored area (49 of them) is a convex "block" that I need to maintain as a separate item when importing into Blender.
However, it appears that once imported, the entire thing becomes ONE object, instead of many.
How do I restore this back to its original configuration, so that I don't have to redraw each "block" from scratch?   Thanks!

[image: AC3d item]

[image: Blender Import]

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this from my knowledge would be to tab into edit mode, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all and then press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose the *Loose Parts* option. However, this only works if each block is not connected to another block. If they are connected, you can still press <kbd>P</kbd> and separate them but you would have to individually select each thing you wanted to separate each time

Comment: 1. To split up the object into loose parts, it is not necessary to select anything 2. The question implies that each separate part has its own material, so maybe separating `P` > _By Material_ might be the best option? (Again, no selection needed for that.)

Comment: Gordn's method worked perfectly, thanks!